Characteristic polynomials identity as corollary of a general identity
Well, given two matrices $A,B$ of size $k\times n$ and $n\times k$ the characteristic polynomials of $AB$ and $BA$ are related, i.e., $\chi_{BA}=\lambda^{n-k}\chi_{AB}$. There are a lot of nice proofs on math.stackexchange, but I found one on math.overflow here: highest score answer, which is presented as corollary of the following general identity on rings: $(1-ba)^{-1}=1+b(1-ab)^{-1}a$.
The identity on characteristic polynomials should follow from $(\lambda I_{n}-BA)^{-1}=\lambda^{-1}(I_n+B(\lambda I_k-AB)^{-1}A)$.
Of course $\det(\lambda I_{n}-BA)^{-1}=\lambda^{-n}\det(I_n+B(\lambda I_k-AB)^{-1}A)$ and, in order to get the desidered equality, $\det(I_n+B(\lambda I_k-AB)^{-1}A)$ should be equal to $\lambda^{k}\det(\lambda I_k-AB)^{-1}$  but, no matter how much I wrap my head around this, I can't find a way to prove it.

The proof I know for generic $A$ and $B$ deals with $\lambda I-BA$ directly rather than with its inverse. See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3110428

There are plenty of proofs. Some very elegant and elementary, the question is about deriving it as a corollary of the stated equality. Thanks for your comment.

(It is also be equivalent to showing $\det(I+B(\lambda I-AB)^{-1}A) = \det(I+A(\lambda I-BA)^{-1}B)$)

Case of square matrices ($n=k$) and $A$, $B$ invertible:
The inversion formula can be rewritten as
$$
(\lambda I_n - BA)^{-1}BA = B(\lambda I_k - AB)^{-1}A.
$$
Without any assumptions, we can take determinants to get
$$\tag{1}
\det(\lambda I_n - BA)^{-1}\det (BA) = \det(B(\lambda I_k - AB)^{-1}A).
$$
In the special case of square matrices ($n=k$) and assuming $A$ and $B$ are invertible, we may conclude $\det(\lambda I_n - BA) = \det(\lambda I_n - AB)$.

Generalization to non-invertible matrices (sketch):
Since the set of singular matrices is nowhere dense, we may pick two sequences of matrices $A_i$ and $B_i$ converging to $A$ and $B$, such that all factors in $(1)$ are invertible when substituting $A_i$ and $B_i$. Hence we get $\det(\lambda I_n - B_iA_i) = \det(\lambda I_n - A_iB_i)$ for all $i$. Take the limit (since everything is continuous) to conclude $\det(\lambda I_n - BA) = \det(\lambda I_n - AB)$.
Note: For such a continuity argument to work, the matrices must be over a certain kind of domain, e.g. $\Bbb R$. But from this we get a polynomial identity, which proves that it holds as well over any (commutative unitary) ring.

Generalization to rectangular matrices:
Assume (without loss of generality) that $k<n$. Then we can make the following block matrix calculation to use the above result:
$$\begin{split}
\det(\lambda I_n - BA)
&= \det\left(\lambda I_n - 
\begin{pmatrix}B & 0\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}A \\ 0\end{pmatrix}
\right)
\\ &= \det\left(\lambda I_n - 
\begin{pmatrix}A \\ 0\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}B & 0\end{pmatrix}
\right)
\\ &= \det\left(\lambda I_n - 
\begin{pmatrix}AB & 0 \\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}
\right)
\\ &= \det
\begin{pmatrix}\lambda I_k - AB & 0 \\ 0 & \lambda I_{n-k}\end{pmatrix}
\lambda^{n-k}\det(\lambda I_k - AB).
\end{split}$$

@ Milten We can consider matrices with generic indeterminates $a_{ij}$ and $b_{ij}$, hence we can simplify the determinants. The case $k\neq n$ should follow from case $n=k$, but maybe there is a direct reasoning.

@Antonio I added a full solution

I think your answer is optimal, i.e., it can not be shortened.
Maybe the density argument can be substituted by using $\mathbb{Z}[a_{ij},b_{k,l}]$ (where $a_{ij}$ are indeterminates). Since the formula works over finite fields too.
It seems there is a missing equal sign at the end of the chain of equalities.

This may not fully satisfy you as an answer, but it was a little too long for a comment:
If you're willing to use the Sylvester determinant identity, or first prove it which can be done in a variety of ways, then you have
$$\det(I_n+B(\lambda I_k-AB)^{-1}A)=\det(I_k+AB(\lambda I_k-AB)^{-1})$$
But
$$I_k+AB(\lambda I_k-AB)^{-1}=I_k+(\lambda I_k-(\lambda I_k-AB))(\lambda I_k-AB)^{-1}=\lambda(\lambda I_k-AB)^{-1}$$
so
$$\det(I_n+B(\lambda I_k-AB)^{-1}A)=\det(\lambda(\lambda I_k-AB)^{-1})=\lambda^k\det(\lambda I_k-AB)^{-1}$$
which is the thing you wanted.

Good point, but from Sylvester determinant identity you get $\det(\lambda I_n-BA)=\lambda^{n-k}\det(\lambda I_k-AB)$ simply by rescaling, i.e., $\det(I_n-\frac{1}{\lambda}BA)=\det(I_k-\frac{1}{\lambda}AB)$. Maybe it's not what the author of the post on math.overflow meant, or maybe my pretense is overly demanding. In any case, the identity you proved it's not trivial (at least for me). Thanks.

P.S. Vice versa, given $\det(\lambda I_n-BA)=\lambda^{n-k}\det(\lambda I_k-AB)$, one gets the Sylvester identity immediately. That's why I didn't want to use it.

@Antonio Yes, hence my initial remark :)
