# how to find an upper bound of the spectral radius

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-methods

I've given the real valued matrix $K=K_1+K_2$, with $K_1$ and $K_2$ symmentric and positiv defined.
Further there are given this 3 matrices:

[image]

with $\omega > 0$ and

[image]

Now I tried the whole day to show this:

[image]

and this:

[image]

Could somebody help me ???

My idea was the following:
In every bracket of the matrix $M$ there is a symmetric positiv defined matrix. Hence we know    $A*B=(B*A)^t$ (here the small t means transposed).
With this in mind I tried to change the order of the brackets in M and the to use the triangle inequality to get the claim, but I didn't reached it.

I would be very happy if someone has a better idea

Answer (score 2):

**Hints.** Here are a few useful facts ($X,Y$ below denote complex square matrices):

1. $\rho(XY)=\rho(YX)$. This follows from a well-known fact that $XY$ and $YX$ have identical characteristic polynomials. (See also [q311342](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/311342/1551).)
2. Normal (including Hermitian) matrices are unitarily diagonalisable. I think this is taught in virtually every introductory course on linear algebra.
3. When both $X,Y$ are normal, their spectral radii coincide with their induced 2-norms and hence $\rho(XY)\le\|XY\|_2\le\|X\|_2\|Y\|_2=\rho(X)\rho(Y)$.
4. For any scalars $\alpha$ and $\beta$, the matrices $\alpha I+X$ and $(\beta I+X)^{-1}$ commute (provided that the latter inverse exists). This is a consequence of [Cayley-Hamilton theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Hamilton_theorem) when applied to the matrix $\beta I+X$.

Comment: thank you a lot. So if I see it right I only need the first point to show change the order of the brackets in $M$ and then apply the third point to get the claim

Comment: @user142665 No. After you permute the order of the brackets cyclically, how do you know that the permuted product is a product of two *normal* matrices? You need fact 2 or fact 4 as well.