# Prove or disprove: For $2\times 2$ matrices $A$ and $B$, if $(AB)^2=0$, then $(BA)^2=0$.

Tags: matrices

My goal is to prove or disprove the following claim:

> For $2\times 2$ matrices $A$ and $B$, if $(AB)^2=0$, then $(BA)^2=0$.

My thoughts on the question:

1. I know that $AB=O$ does not imply that $BA=O$, so my first impression was that it is false. I tried the counter-example I know but it leads to $(BA)^2=O$.
2. (*edited*) As pointed out by Friedrich Philipp in the comments, $A$ or $B$ is not invertible. If one of them is invertible, then the question is easily shown to be true. I wish to avoid density arguments though, so I am still stuck with the case where $A$ and $B$ are both singular.
3. The question is in a list of  prove or disprove questions for square matrices of any order. This specific one precise that $A$ and $B$ are of order $2$, so maybe the property is true for these matrices. I seems to remember that if $M$ is a square matrix of order $n$ and is nilpotent, then the order of nilpotence (the smallest $p$ such that $M^p=O$) is at most $n$, but I don't know how to use it here.

Beside this, I am clueless. I am looking for ideas or hints on the problem.

Comment: $AB=0$ implies $(BA)^2=BABA=B(AB)A=0$.

Comment: @Wilf-Fine So what? ;-) Taladris: "$A$ and $B$ are not invertible": I doubt that.

Comment: But I don't know if $AB=O$. Maybe my first comment is confusing: I meant that I initially thought the statement is false, and to find a counter-example, I can just take $A$ and $B$ such that $AB=O$ but $BA\neq O$. Then trivially $(AB)^2=O$ but hopefully we would have $(BA)^2\neq O$... which doesn't happen in the example I tried. My question is really about the statement in the title.

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp: you are right! One of them is not invertible, but maybe not both.I'll edit my question

Comment: $(BA)^3=BABABA=B0A=0$

Comment: @Michael That's good. So, the minimal polynomial of $BA$ divides $t^3$. Thus, it is either $t$ or $t^2$ so that $(BA)^2 = 0$.

Comment: If A invertable

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the fact that for a $2\times 2$ matrix $C$, $C^2 - tr(C) C + \det(C) I_2 = 0_2$.
Conclude that if $C$ is a $2\times 2$ matrix and $C^2=0$, then both the trace and the determinant of $C$ are 0. Then use the fact that $AB$ and $BA$ have the same trace and determinant.

Answer (score 2):

In general, if $A$ is $m\times n$ and $B$ is $n\times m$ are two arbitrary matrices, [the nonzero eigenvalues of $AB$ and $BA$ (counting multiplicity) must be identical](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/311362) . Therefore, if $AB$ is nilpotent, $BA$ must be nilpotent too and $(BA)^{\max\{m,n\}}=0$.