# Let $A$ and $B$ be matrices over $\mathbb C$. Then pick out the correct statements.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

> Let  $A$ and $B$  be matrices over $\mathbb C$. Then,
>
> 1. $AB$  and $BA$   always have the same set of eigenvalues.
> 2. If  $AB$  and  $BA$  have the same set of eigenvalues then $AB=BA$.
> 3. If  $A^{-1}$   exists then  $AB$  and $BA$   are similar.
> 4. The rank of  $AB$  is always the same as the  rank of   $BA$ .

1. Suppose $AB=BA$
   Let $x$ be the eigen vector of $A$ corresponding to the eigenvalue $a$. $$ABx=BAx=aBx \implies Bx$$ is the eigen vector of $A$. If the eigen space corresponding to the eigen values of $A$ is one. Then, $Bx=\lambda x \implies x$ is the eigen vector of $B$. So $AB$ and $BA$ have same set of eigen values. statement is false. Am I correct?
2. I don't know, How to judge the statement.
3. I don't know, How to judge the statement.
4. Statement is false, I could obtain the counter examples.

Please check my answers. Please help me.

Comment: In your argument for (1), it looks like you're assuming that $AB=BA$. Do you mean to do that?

Comment: sorry, I had network problem yesterday. No.Actually, I was trying to show,  At what condition 1. is true. @GTonyJacobs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.See the reference helpfully provided below.

2. This is false. Choose any two invertible matrices which do not commute with each other. By (3), $AB$ and $BA$ are similar and therefore have the same eigenvalues.
3. This is  true since $A^{-1}(AB)A=BA.$
4. This is false. Choose any two matrices such that $AB$ is $0$ but $BA$ is not $0$.

You might find the example of two matrices given below to be quite useful when checking other conjectures about singular matrices.

$\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$ $\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$=$\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$,
 $\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$ $\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$=$\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: What are the $2$ by $2$ matrices which disprove this conjecture in 1?

Comment: Your matrices are not counterexample to 1, because they have the same set of eigenvalues $\{0\}$.

Comment: I was giving extra help to Maneesh not answering your question which I have only just seen. Interchanging the 0 and 1 in the first column of my second matrix  answers your query.

Comment: Still no. The statement 1 is true. In general, the characteristic polynomial of $AB$ is identical to the characteristic polynomial of $BA$. The proof is seen here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/311342/do-ab-and-ba-have-same-minimal-and-characteristic-polynomials

Comment: Yes, I stand corrected. It is the eigenvectors which need not be the same.