# A matrix trace relation

Tags: matrices

Is it true $tr(\mu\mu^{T}A) = \mu^{T}A\mu$, where $\mu$ is vector of opropriate order?

I verified it for $3\times3$ case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. In general, regardless of the sizes of the matrices $X$ and $Y$, if $XY$ and $YX$ are legitimate matrix multiplications, then [the two matrix products have the same nonzero eigenvalues](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/311362) and hence the same traces.