# Can it be proved that non-symmetric matrix $A$ will always have real eigen values?.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus

Let $M$ be a $2 \times 2$ real symmetric matrix and it is well known/proved that it will always have  two real eigenvalues.
Now let
$$\Sigma = \begin{bmatrix} 
    0 & k \\
    1 & 0
    \end{bmatrix}$$,

Where $k \in {\cal R}$ and $k \ne 1$. I found that the non-symmetric matrix $A=\Sigma M \Sigma$ always has real eigen values for all k except $k=1$ (for $k=1$, it becomes a symmetric matrix) Numerically.

Can anyone prove that non-symmetric matrix $A=\Sigma M \Sigma$ will always have real eigen values ??

Matrix $A$ is pseudo-symmetric under the constant metric,
$$\eta = \begin{bmatrix} 
    1/k & 0 \\
    0 & k
    \end{bmatrix}$$
as $\eta A \eta^{-1} = A^{T}$.

Comment: @James Oh! Sorry, one typo was there, Now you please read it again.

Comment: I shall remove my comment as it is no longer needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, if $X$ and $Y$ are two rectangular matrices such that both $XY$ and $YX$ make sense, then [$XY$ and $YX$ share the same nonzero eigenvalues](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/311362).

So, the nonzero eigenvalues of $\Sigma M\Sigma$ are those of $\Sigma^2M=kM$. Now the conclusion follows.

Comment: See this please: [link] (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2607649/real-eigenvalues-of-a-non-symmetric-matrix-a)