# Real eigenvalues of a non-symmetric matrix $A$ ?.

Tags: matrices, linear-transformations, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus, matrix-decomposition

Let $M$ be a $2 \times 2$ real symmetric matrix and it is well known/proved that it will always have  two real eigenvalues.
Now let
$$\Sigma(k) = \begin{bmatrix} 
    0 & k \\
    1 & 0
    \end{bmatrix}$$,

Where $k \in {\cal R}$ and $k \ne 1$. I find that the non-symmetric matrix $A=\Sigma(k) M \Sigma(l)$ has real eigenvalues for $~kl>0$ (for $k=l=1$, it becomes a symmetric matrix) Numerically.

Can anyone prove that  $A=\Sigma(k) M \Sigma(l)$ will have real eigenvalues for $~kl>0$ ??

Comment: @user1551 See if You can help me.

Comment: just study if the system of linear equations defined by $$\Sigma(k) M\Sigma(l)\cdot(x_1,x_2)^T=\lambda\cdot (x_1,x_2)^T$$ is solvable for two real $\lambda$. Or find the roots of it characteristic polynomial.

Comment: @Masacroso Thanks!,

Comment: @Masacroso If I take  $M = \begin{bmatrix} 
    a & b \\
    b & c
    \end{bmatrix}$, then its eigenvalues are  $\frac{1}{2} \left( a l+c k \mp \sqrt{a^2 l^2+(4 b^2-2 a c  )k l+c^2 k^2} \right)$. Now Can it be proved from here, that these two equations are real for $kl >0$

Comment: @Sachin Note that the expression inside the square root is $4b^2 + (al)^2 -2(al)(ck) + (ck)^2 = 4b^2kl + (al - ck)^2$. Ik $kl$ is positive, then this expression cannot be negative, and you get your real eigenvalues. To get _one_ solution with $kl>0$, you need $b = 0$ and $c = al/k$, which is possible, so $kl>0$ alone isn't enough to guarantee _two_ real eigenvalues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $kl>0$, $\Sigma(l)$ is invertible and $A=\Sigma(k) M \Sigma(l)$ is similar to
$$
B=\Sigma(l)\Sigma(k) M=\pmatrix{l&0\\ 0&k}M=\operatorname{sgn}(l)\pmatrix{|l|&0\\ 0&|k|}M,
$$
which in turn is similar to the real symmetric matrix
$$
C=\operatorname{sgn}(l)\pmatrix{\sqrt{|l|}&0\\ 0&\sqrt{|k|}}M\pmatrix{\sqrt{|l|}&0\\ 0&\sqrt{|k|}}.
$$
Hence the result.

Comment: See if you can help me here too https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2616630/condition-for-pseudo-orthogonality