# Do $\sqrt{A}BA^*B\sqrt{A}$ and $ABA^*B$ have the same eigenvalues?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, operator-theory, mathematical-physics

Do $\sqrt{A}BA^*B\sqrt{A}$ and $ABA^*B$ have the same eigenvalues? where $A$ is a 4 by 4 positive-semidefinite hermitian matrix and $\text{tr}A=1$ and $B=\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0  \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0  \\ -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: See here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/311342/do-ab-and-ba-have-same-minimal-and-characteristic-polynomials.
Cyclic permutation of a product of square matrices always preserves its eigenvalues, including their multiplicities.