# Given that $A$ and $B$ be $n \times n$ matrices over $\mathbb{C}$ then choose the correct option

Tags: linear-algebra

> Given that  $A$ and $B$  be  $n \times  n$ matrices   over  $\mathbb{C}$. Then choose the correct options
>
> $(1)$ $AB$  and $BA $  always  have the same set  of eigenvalues
>
> $(2)$ If $AB$ and $ BA$ have  same  set   of eigenvalue  then AB = BA
>
> $(3)$ If $A ^{-1}$  exist  then $AB$ and $BA$  are  similar
>
> $(4)$ The rank of $AB$  is always  same  as the  ranks  of $BA$

**My attempt:**

I thinks all option $1,2,3,4$  will be  correct if   take $A=B= I$

Any hints/solution will be appreciated

Thank you!

Comment: 3) is true and the rest are false.

Comment: You are being asked to check some set of statements for a lot of choices of $A$ and $B$. Checking only $A =B = I$ does not verify the given statements.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy  sir   any  counter example  for  option $2)$

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг..okss  im trying

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy: How 1 is false ? can you explain sir?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy: I found this post :(https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/311342/do-ab-and-ba-have-same-minimal-and-characteristic-polynomials) so its true. May be the eigenvectors are need not same! Any comments ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$1.$is false. Take A= $\begin{pmatrix}1&2\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$ $B=\begin{pmatrix}2&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$

$2.$  is false. $A=\begin{pmatrix}2&1\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$ $B=\begin{pmatrix}2&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$

$3.$ is True  because  $A^{-1}(AB)A=BA.$

$4.$ is false.

Comment: In your example for 1, $AB = \begin{pmatrix}2&2\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$ and $BA = \begin{pmatrix}2&4\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$, both of which have eigenvalues $1$ and $2$.

Comment: @JimmyK4542 thanks for correction

Comment: @JimmyK4542 can u help me ?  to find out counter example  for  $1$

Comment: @jasmine: 1 is true. see (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/311342/do-ab-and-ba-have-same-minimal-and-characteristic-polynomials) for details!

Comment: @ChinnapparajR thanks u