# Prove $XX^T$ and $X^T X$ have same eigenvalues with same multiplicity

Tags: linear-algebra

Same eigenvalues can be shown easily $XX'v=\lambda v \implies X'X(X'v)=\lambda (X'v)$ and similarly for $XX'$ case.

But it is hard to see immediately how engienspace of each $\lambda $have same dimensionality for $XX', X'X$.

I know this is true from SVD but I don't want to use it here because I look forward to proving SVD using this as a corollary.

Comment: I don't believe this is true, the two matrices may not even be the same size. (Take $X$ to be an $n \times 1$ matrix, for example.)

Comment: @angryavian I don't see how is that a counter-example.

Comment: Surely your computation shows that a reasonable candidate map from the $\lambda$-espace of $XX'$ to that of $X'X$ is $v \mapsto X'v$. The only question is whether it has a kernel that intersects the $\lambda$-eigenspace. The tough case will probably be $\lambda = 0$, but maybe not. Anyhow, have you tried looking at that map?

Comment: @JohnHughes Yes I did. I can't quite make sense of it. If $X$ is invertible or something this would be trivial.

Comment: @DanielLi Say, $X = (1,0,\ldots, 0)^\top$. Then $X^\top X = 1$ which has no zero eigenvalues, but $XX^\top$ has zero as an eigenvalue with high multiplicity. Anyway, just trying to get you to notice that your claim should be adjusted somehow, for example by focusing on nonzero eigenvalues...

Comment: Shouldn't the q. be restricted to square matrices?

Comment: Otherwise, as @angryavian have suggested, vector-matrix $\ [1\ 0\ 0\ 0\ 0 \ 0\ 0]\ $ (or simply $\ [1\ 0])$ is a counterexample.

Comment: The "mark as duplicate" by @user1551 is mistaken; that related question is for square matrices, while this one is not. (As it happens, some answers in that question address the non-square case, however.)

Comment: @JohnHughes While the question is about square matrices, the answers are not. See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/311362) for instance.

Comment: Uh...that's exactly what I said. But you marked this as a duplicate *question*, which I believe is a mistake. I suppose in the greater scheme, it doesn't really matter. OP has the answer at this point from several comments.