# Showing $A^x B A^{1-x}$ have same eigenvalues regardless of $x$

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $A$ and $B$ are positive-definite and $x\in [0, 1]$. How do I show that eigenvalues of the following quantity are the same regardless of $x$?

$$ A^x B A^{1-x}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $A$ is positive definite, $A^x$ is unambiguously defined on $\mathbb R$ using primary matrix function. Thus $A^{1-x}A^x=A$ and the result follows because $XY$ and $YX$ have the same spectra when $X$ and $Y$ are square matrices (so that the spectrum of $A^xBA^{1-x}$ is always equal to that of $AB$).

Comment: how do I know that XY and YX have the same spectra?

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov See the various answers of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/311342), for instances.