# Find eigenvalues of specific matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> Let the entries of $n \times n$ matrix $A$, where $n \ge 3$, be $$a_{ij} = \frac{((-1)^{i+j}+1)}{2}$$ Find all eigenvalues and multiplicity of $A$.

---

By nullity I know that $\lambda=0$ has multiplicity $n-2$, but the two other eigenvalues are hard to calculate. I know that those two eigenvalues sum up with $n$ by the trace. How could I calculate the rest eigenvalues without just predicting the eigenvalue? (E.g. Plugging $\lambda=\frac{n}{2}$)

Comment: "By nullity, I know $\lambda=0$ has multiplicity $2$" How? What is the rank of $A$?

Comment: @above that's a typo. It's $n-2$

Comment: Ok thanks for the clarificaiton

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $v=\left(-1,1,-1,1,\ldots,(-1)^n)\right)^T$ and $e=(1,1,\ldots,1)^T$. Then $A=\frac{vv^T+ee^T}{2}=\frac12\pmatrix{v&e}\pmatrix{v&e}^T$. [Therefore](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/311362) $A$ has the same multi-set of nonzero eigenvalues as
$$
B=\frac12\pmatrix{v&e}^T\pmatrix{v&e}=\frac12\pmatrix{n&\frac{(-1)^n-1}{2}\\ \frac{(-1)^n-1}{2}&n},
$$
i.e. its eigenvalues are $\frac12\left[n\pm\frac{(-1)^n-1}{2}\right]$ and $n-2$ copies of zeros.