# Let $A_{n×n}$ be a complex matrix then prove that $ch_{AB}(x) = ch_{BA}(x)$

Tags: matrices, nilpotence, characteristic-polynomial

Let $A_{n×n}$ be a complex matrix then prove that $ch_{AB}(x) = ch_{BA}(x)$

I saw somewhere that $ch_{AB}(x) = ch_{BA}(x)$ if $A$ is invertible and if $AB$ is nilpotent then $BA$ is nilpotent. What happened if $A$ is singular.

Comment: Can you explain what ch is supposed to represent?

Comment: Here $ch_A(x)$ denotes characteristic polynomial of matrix $A$

Comment: The reason it's easy if $A$ is invertible is that then $AB$ and $BA$ are similar via $A$. To prove the general case, you can either use a continuity argument (by first proving that the set of invertible matrices is dense), or you can use an [algebraic argument.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/311342/do-matrices-ab-and-ba-have-the-same-minimal-and-characteristic-polynomia/311362#311362)

Comment: @Anonymous, I don't know how can we use concept of real analysis in linear algebra.

Comment: Fix the matrix $B$. Consider the set of $n \times n$ complex matrices to be $C^{n^2}$. It is easy to see that the coefficients of the polynomial $\operatorname{ch}_{AB} - \operatorname{ch}_{BA}$ are continuous functions of the $n^2$ coefficients of the matrix $A$. Each of these coefficients is zero for all invertible $A$. Since the invertible matrices form a dense set, these coefficients are identically zero. (I understand that if you haven't seen this kind of argument before, then you have a lot of things to think about.)