# A similarity-like transfromation with left-invertible matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, similar-matrices, generalized-inverse

Suppose $X\in \mathbb R^{m\times n}$ $(m>n)$ is a left-invertible matrix, and its left-inverse is $X^+=(X^\top X)^{-1}X^\top$ (so that $X^+X=I$).

Now I have a matrix $A\in \mathbb R^{n\times n}$. Define $B\triangleq XAX^+$.

By computing some examples, I observe that the eigenvalues of $B$ are the same as the ones of $A$ apart from additional ($m-n$) zero eigenvalues. For example,
$A=\begin{bmatrix}
1   & -2         \\
3  & 4     
 \end{bmatrix}$, $X=\begin{bmatrix}
1   & 0         \\
1  & 1 \\
0 & 1    
 \end{bmatrix}$. Then $eig(A)=\{2.5000 + 1.9365i,
   2.5000 - 1.9365i\}$, and $eig(B)=\{2.5000 + 1.9365i,
   2.5000 - 1.9365i, 0\}$

Is it always true?

Comment: This follows directly from the fact that for any pair of (possibly rectangular) matrices $X$ and $Y$ of appropriate sizes, $XY$ and $YX$ share the same multi-set of nonzero eigenvalues. See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/311362) for a proof. This result was first discovered by J.J. Sylvester in mid-1800's.

Comment: Amazing. Thanks for pointing it out.