# When do $AB$ and $BA$ have the same singular spectrum?

Tags: linear-algebra

For example AB and BA have the same singular spectrum (singular values) for matrices below, is there a general characterization of cases when

- singular spectrum is the same?
- non-zero singular spectrum is the same?

$$A=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 11 & 9 \\
 9 & 11 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

$$B=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 4 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

$$\sigma(AB)=\sigma(BA)=\langle \sqrt{3 \sqrt{324721}+1717},\frac{160}{\sqrt{3 \sqrt{324721}+1717}}\rangle$$

A related question is when $AB$ and $BA$ have the same non-zero spectrum, the answer is "always". (proof for square matrices [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/311342/do-matrices-ab-and-ba-have-the-same-minimal-and-characteristic-polynomia))

Comment: One sufficient condition seems that $AB(AB)^T=BA(BA)^T$