# How to find the characteristic polynomial of the given matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, characteristic-polynomial

I am stuck at finding the characteristic polynomial of the following matrix.
$$A=\begin{bmatrix}
  \ell a^2 & a & a &  a&\dotso & \dotso& a &a
  \\
  a &  t &0&0
 & \dotso & \dotso &0&0
 \\
 a & 0 & t &0 &\dotso
 & \dotso & 0 &0
 \\
 a & 0& 0& t &\dotso
 & \dotso &0 &0
 \\
 \dotso & \dotso& \dotso& \dotso &\dotso
 & \dotso & \dotso & \dotso
 \\
 \dotso & \dotso& \dotso& \dotso &\dotso
 & \dotso & \dotso & \dotso
 \\
 \dotso & \dotso& \dotso& \dotso &\dotso
 & \dotso & \dotso & \dotso
 \\
 a&  0 &0&0
 & \dotso & \dotso&t&0
 \\
 a&  0 &0&0
 & \dotso & \dotso&0&t
   \end{bmatrix}_{(\ell+1) \times (\ell +1)}.$$

Here $t,l,a$ are constants.

**My try**: The characteristic polynomial of the matrix is $\det(xI-A).

We have, $\det(xI-A)=\begin{bmatrix}
  x-\ell a^2 & -a & -a &  -a&\dotso & \dotso& -a &-a
  \\
  -a &  x-t &0&0
 & \dotso & \dotso &0&0
 \\
 -a & 0 & x-t &0 &\dotso
 & \dotso & 0 &0
 \\
 -a & 0& 0& x-t &\dotso
 & \dotso &0 &0
 \\
 \dotso & \dotso& \dotso& \dotso &\dotso
 & \dotso & \dotso & \dotso
 \\
 \dotso & \dotso& \dotso& \dotso &\dotso
 & \dotso & \dotso & \dotso
 \\
 \dotso & \dotso& \dotso& \dotso &\dotso
 & \dotso & \dotso & \dotso
 \\
 -a&  0 &0&0
 & \dotso & \dotso&x-t&0
 \\
 -a&  0 &0&0
 & \dotso & \dotso&0&x-t
   \end{bmatrix}_{(\ell+1) \times (\ell +1)}.$

I expanded along the last row.
I got $(x-t)\times\det(M)-a \times \det (N)$ where

$M=\begin{bmatrix}
  x-\ell a^2 & -a &-a &  -a&\dotso & \dotso& -a 
  \\
  -a &  t &0&0
 & \dotso & \dotso &0
 \\
 -a & 0 &t &0 &\dotso
 & \dotso & 0 
 \\
 -a & 0& 0& t &\dotso
 & \dotso &0 
 \\
 \dotso & \dotso& \dotso& \dotso &\dotso
 & \dotso & \dotso
 \\
 \dotso & \dotso& \dotso& \dotso &\dotso
 & \dotso & \dotso
 \\
 \dotso & \dotso& \dotso& \dotso &\dotso
 & \dotso & \dotso
 \\
 -a&  0 &0&0
 & \dotso & \dotso&t\end{bmatrix}$
and $N=\begin{bmatrix}
  -a &-a &  -a&\dotso & \dotso& -a 
  \\
   x-t &0&0
 & \dotso & \dotso &0
 \\
 0 &x-t &0 &\dotso
 & \dotso & 0 
 \\
 0& 0& x-t &\dotso
 & \dotso &0 
 \\
 \dotso& \dotso& \dotso &\dotso
 & \dotso & \dotso
 \\
 \dotso & \dotso& \dotso& \dotso &\dotso
 & \dotso 
 \\
 \dotso & \dotso& \dotso& \dotso &\dotso
 & \dotso 
 \\
 0 &0&0
 & \dotso & x-t&0\end{bmatrix}$.

But I am stuck from here. Can someone please help me out?

**Also, it is my request to everyone that please don't delete my question. This is my first question. I am trying really hard to show to the community what I have tried in the question. I am not so good at writing, I am a first year student studying Bachelors in Mathematics.**

Comment: Well, do you know $\det N$? If so, the structure of your new matrix $M$ is almost the same as the old matrix, except smaller, except for the issue that the value of $\ell$ should be smaller but it isn't. That suggests that you replace the $\ell$ in the top left corner with another variable and then induct on $\ell$.

Comment: Also it looks like you're only computing the determinant. To compute the characteristic polynomial you'd need to introduce yet another variable.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan; I have edited the question. But I am unable to understand how to use induction on $\ell$ as you suggested. Will it be possible for you to give a detailed answer

Comment: Is $\ell $ even or odd?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $u=(\ell a^2-t,a,a,\ldots,a)^T$ and $v=(0,a,a,\ldots,a)^T$. Then
$$
A=tI+\pmatrix{u&e_1&0&\cdots&0}\pmatrix{e_1^T\\ v^T\\ 0\\ \vdots\\ 0}=:tI+XY.
$$
Therefore
$$
\begin{aligned}
\det(xI-A)
&=\det((x-t)I-XY)\\
&=\det((x-t)I-YX)\quad\text{(Sylvester’s secular theorem)}\\
&=\det\left[(x-t)I-\pmatrix{\ell a^2-t&1\\ \ell a^2&0\\ &&0_{(\ell-1)\times(\ell-1)}}\right]\\
&=\det\pmatrix{x-\ell a^2&-1\\ -\ell a^2&x-t\\ &&(x-t)I_{\ell-1}}\\
&=\big[x^2-(\ell a^2+t)x+\ell a^2(t-1)\big](x-t)^{\ell-1}.\\
\end{aligned}
$$

**Remark.** If you prefer a more elementary proof, you may use elementary row and column operations. Let
$$
B=A-tI
=\pmatrix{\ell a^2-t&a&\cdots&a\\ a&0&\cdots&0\\ \vdots&\vdots&&\vdots\\ a&0&\cdots&0}.
$$
Subtract the second row of $B$ from other rows below it. Then add to the third, fourth,... up to the last column to the second column to obtain the matrix
$$
C=\left(\begin{array}{c|c}\begin{matrix}\ell a^2-t&\ell a\\ a&0\end{matrix}&\ast\\ \hline 0_{(\ell-1)\times 2}&0_{(\ell-1)\times(\ell-1)}\end{array}\right).
$$
Note that the row and column operations above amount to a similarity transform $C=PBP^{-1}$ for some invertible matrix $P$. It follows that
$$
\begin{aligned}
\det(xI-A)
&=\det((x-t)I-B)\\
&=\det((x-t)I-C)\\
&=\det\left(\begin{array}{c|c}\begin{matrix}x-\ell a^2&-\ell a\\ -a&x-t\end{matrix}&\ast\\ \hline 0_{(\ell-1)\times2}&(x-t)I_{\ell-1}\end{array}\right)\\
&=\big[x^2-(\ell a^2+t)x+\ell a^2(t-1)\big](x-t)^{\ell-1}.\\
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: I am sorry but I don't understand the solution. What is "Sylvester's Secular Theorem"? Is it not possible to do it in some easier way? Maybe by using some inductive steps. Also what is $e_1$?

Comment: Since its my first year, I dont think I have learned Linear Algebra so much, I guess

Comment: @Andrea Sylvester’s secular theorem: for any two square matrices $X$ and $Y$ over a commutative ring $R$, $XY$ and $YX$ have the same characteristic polynomial. A short algebraic proof can be found in J. H. Williamson, [The characteristic polynomials of $AB$ and $BA$](https://doi.org/10.1017/S0950184300003104), Edinburgh Mathematical Notes , Volume 39 , January 1954 , p. 13. See also an alternative proof [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/311362).

Answer (score 0):

By induction

$$\det M=\det \left[\begin{array}{ccccc}a&b_1&b_2&\ldots&b_n\\b_1&c_1&0&\ldots&0\\b_2&0&c_2&\ldots&0\\\ldots&\ldots&\ldots&\ldots&0\\b_n&0&0&\ldots&c_n\end{array}\right]=c_1\ldots c_n\left(a-\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{b_k^2}{c_k}\right).$$
Application: if $b_1=\dots=b_n=b$ and $c_1=\ldots=c_n=c$ then
$$\det(M-\lambda I_{n+1})=(c-\lambda)^{n-1}[(a-\lambda)(c-\lambda)-nb^2].$$ Edit: this shows that $M$ is positive definite if and only if $a>0 $ and $ac>nb^2.$