How to show the trace distance is a metric on the space of positive semidefinite matrices?
Let $\mathbb{S}^d_{+}$ be the space of all the $d \times d$ symmetric positive semidefinite matrices. For any $A, B \in \mathbb{S}^d_{+}$, we define
$$d (A, B) = \left[\mathrm{tr}\left(A + B - 2 (A^{1/2} B A^{1/2} )^{1/2}\right) \right]^{1/2},$$
where $\mathrm{tr} (\cdot)$ is the trace of a matrix and $A^{1/2}$ denotes the square root of the positive semidefinite matrix $A$.
How can we show that $d (A, B)$ is a metric on $\mathbb{S}^d_{+}$?
Namely, we need to show that $d (A, B)$ is non-negative, symmetric, vanishes if and only if $A = B$, and satisfies the triangle inequality.
There are some questions regarding to the trace of a square root of matrices Question 1 Question 2 Question 3.
Thanks in advance!

Can you show what you have tried so far? You have already mentioned the 4 defining characteristics of a metric, so showing where you got stuck can allow us to help you better.

@mhdadk Thanks very much for your reminder! I have added some details. And the remaining question is to show that the triangle inequality holds.

Let $f(A,B)=\operatorname{tr}\left(A+B-2(A^{1/2}BA^{1/2})^{1/2}\right)$. (Note that $d(A,B)$ is well-defined only when $f$ is nonnegative.) By Sylvester’s secular theorem, $A^{1/2}BA^{1/2}=(A^{1/2}B^{1/2})(B^{1/2}A^{1/2})$ and $B^{1/2}AB^{1/2}=(B^{1/2}A^{1/2})(A^{1/2}B^{1/2})$ have the same spectrum. It follows that their square roots also have the same spectrum and $f(A,B)$ is symmetric.
Let $X=A^{1/2},\,Y=B^{1/2}$ and $U$ be the unitary factor in the polar decomposition of $XY$, so that $XY=(XY^2X)^{1/2}U=(A^{1/2}BA^{1/2})^{1/2}U$. Then $XYU^\ast$ is positive semidefinite) and
\begin{align}
f(A,B)&=\operatorname{tr}\left(A+B-2(A^{1/2}BA^{1/2})^{1/2}\right)\\
&=\operatorname{tr}\left(X^2+Y^2-2XYU^\ast\right)\tag{1}\\
&=\operatorname{tr}\left(X^2+UY^2U^\ast-XYU^\ast-UYX\right)\\
&=\operatorname{tr}\left((X-UY)(X-YU^\ast)\right)\\
&=\|X-UY\|_F^2\\
&\ge0.\\
\end{align}
Now we may define
$$
d(A,B)=(f(A,B))^{1/2}=\left[\operatorname{tr}\left(A+B-2(A^{1/2}BA^{1/2})^{1/2}\right)\right]^{1/2}=\|X-UY\|_F.
$$
It is not hard to see that $U$ is the maximiser of the real part of $\operatorname{tr}(XYQ)$ among all unitary matrices $Q$. Hence from $(1)$, we obtain the following variational characterisation:
$$
d(A,B)=\min_{U\in U(n)}\|A^{1/2}-UB^{1/2}\|_F.
$$
This also clearly shows that $d(A,B)$ is symmetric.
If $d(A,B)$ vanishes, then $X=UY$ and hence $B=Y^2=YU^\ast UY=X^\ast X=X^2=A$. Conversely, if $A=B$, clearly $d(A,B)=0$.
Finally, let $C$ be a positive semidefinite matrix, $Z=C^{1/2}$ and $V,W$ be the unitary factors in the polar decompositions of $YZ$ and $XZ$ respectively. Then
\begin{align}
d(A,C)
&=\|X-WZ\|_F\\
&\le\|X-UVZ\|_F\\
&\le\|X-UY\|_F+\|UY-UVZ\|_F\\
&=\|X-UY\|_F+\|Y-VZ\|_F\\
&=d(A,B)+d(B,C).
\end{align}

(+1) slick answer. By “Sylvester’s secular theorem”, are you referring to Sylvester’s law of inertia?

@mhdadk Sylvester’s secular theorem: for any two square matrices $A$ and $B$ of the same size over the same commutative ring, $AB$ and $BA$ have the same characteristic polynomial (and hence the same spectrum). More generally, if $A$ is $m\times n$, $B$ is $n\times m$ and $m\ge n$, the char. poly. of $AB$ is $x^{m-n}$ times the char. poly. of $BA$ (see https://math.stackexchange.com/a/311362 ). This was first discovered by J.J. Sylvester. Characteristic equations were called secular equations in the old days. Hence I call it a “secular theorem”.

@user1551 Can we use the variational characterization of $d (A, B)$ to show that $d^2 (A, B)$ is convex with respect to $A$ for fixed $B$?

@Aphelios I don’t know whether the variational characterisation is helpful or not, but the mapping $B\mapsto d(A,B)^2=f(A,B)=\operatorname{tr}\left(A+B-2(A^{1/2}BA^{1/2})^{1/2}\right)$ is clearly convex because $X\mapsto X^{1/2}$ is concave on the set of all PSD matrices.
